# hyperlink who's path is only a forward slash (/)

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have been asked to make some changes to a friend's company website. It uses a PHP insert file for the header on each page, which is useful as the navigation etc is the same on every page.

**The following code designates the company logo on every page:**

```
<div id="logo"> 
    <a href="/"></a> 
</div>
```

As you can see, the `href` of the `a` tag contains *only* a forward slash `/` as it's path.

The link is working fine, and connects to the `index.php` page.

I'm wondering how it is doing this? Seeing as the default page for the domain is controlled by the server config file, is this a shortcut to link to whatever the default page is designated as?

I've never seen this done before, and I can't seem to find any documentation concerning it. I appreciate any information you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That link brings you to the public root, and then the default file kicks in.

It's the relative equivalent of an absolute path, such as `http://stackoverflow.com/`

> In Linux and other Unix-like operating systems, a forward slash is used to represent the root directory, which is the directory that is at the top of the directory hierarchy and that contains all other directories and files on the system. Thus every absolute path, which is the address of a filesystem object (e.g., file or directory) relative to the root directory, begins with a forward slash.
>
> Forward slashes are also used in URLs (universal resource locators) to separate directories and files, because URLs are based on the UNIX directory structure. A major difference from the UNIX usage is that they begin with a scheme (e.g., http or ftp) rather than a root directory represented by a forward slash and that the scheme is followed directly by the sequence of a colon and two consecutive forward slashes to indicate the start of the directories and file portion of the URL.

via: http://www.linfo.org/forward_slash.html

Comment: Much appreciated sir. Very good answer. I was able to logically deduce as much, but it's always nice to have some documentation, and fellow minds, to back my logic up!

Answer (score 6):

It is a [relative URI](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/test/rel_examples1.html). Since it consists of just the path part, it maintains the current scheme, host, port etc and so takes you to http://www.example.com/ (assuming you were on http://www.example.com/foo/bar?baz=x#123 )

The browser then requests `/` from `www.example.com` using `http` on the default port (80).

The server then devices what send back. How it does this depends on what the server is and how it is configured.

Since you mention `index.php` there will be something that tells the server to use that.

If we use Apache as an example, that will be a combination of the [DirectoryIndex directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) and something to tell Apache [how to handle PHP programmes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).

Comment: So, let's say I have been asked to change the DirectoryIndex directive (which I have in this case); I'm assuming this link will then connect with whatever file is designated in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Assuming you use a .htaccess file to do it and that the system supports .htaccess and has support for them turned on — yes.