# What is the use of href="/"? in anchor tag?

Tags: html

I've seen it in many website and I was wondering what it does. 
If someone could clear my doubt it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/` means the root of the current project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hyperlink who's path is only a forward slash (/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612888/hyperlink-whos-path-is-only-a-forward-slash)

Comment: @AsheshKumarSingh what exactly is "the current project" in terms of internet URLs?

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of http urls (hyperlinks):

1. Absolute, includes full domain : `http://example.com/folder/foo.htm`
2. Relative to current document: `folder/foo.bar`
3. Relative to current domain: `/folder/foo.bar` - note `/` at the beginning.

This url `/` belongs to third group - it defines default document at the domain root.

So click on `<a href="/">Go home</a>` will navigate to the domain frontpage.

Answer (score 0):

This `/` means the root directory from that app or website... A couple of examples...

Let's suppose you have a django app in `/home/me/pythonprojects/demo1` with this approach, the `/` in your django apps would point to demo1 location.

Or in apache when you have `/var/www/html/project1`, the `/` from project1 will be that absolute adress, this way you can have project1, project2,..., projectX in the `/var/www/html` directory and all of these apps will have their own `/` and you will not care where your app is in.

Hope it is a bit clearer