# How to refer back to index.html in the root directory when i'm currently in a subdirectory

Tags: html, django

This is an embarassingly noobish question but here goes....

I have a web directory structure as follows:

```
   index.html
   |_____/account/
   |_____/random-tweet/
```

In my random-tweet.html here is my code:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Clicking on this however tries to bring me to random-tweet/index.html as the url is currently 
http://localhost:7000/random-tweet/

How to change the link so it brings me back to index.html in root directory??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read [hyperlink-whos-path-is-only-a-forward-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612888/hyperlink-whos-path-is-only-a-forward-slash) for more information.

Comment: can you post your urls.py?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In random-tweet.html change the link to:

```
<a href="../">Home</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your answer, but please provide an explanation so others can understand how this code fixes the problem.